# Camera collision in BabylonJS

Tags: babylonjs

I'm trying to make a camera not overlap with meshes. Here I reproduced what is happening https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#4NHCRD#4 You can see that the small ball with an attached camera can see through the big ball on collide.

I've tried all tricks from here https://doc.babylonjs.com/divingDeeper/cameras/camera_collisions but no success :pensive:

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust minZ-property of the camera:

```
crCamera.minZ = 0.01
```